# Uniqueness Constraints feature requires Xcode 7.0 tools or later

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I'm running Xcode 8.3 and I wanted to add constraints to one of Core Data entities. That's an error I'm getting:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, instead of editing this in a text editor, you can do it from the XCode UI. Click on the xcdatamodel file, and choose the "Show the File inspector" tab in the tabs of inspectors on the right side of the screen. You will see a dropdown for the Tools Version. Here is an illustration:

[image: XCode inspector area where you can edit the tools version]

Answer (score 2):

In case anybody has the same problem.

Just open your .xcdatamodel file with text editor. Find `minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 4.3"` in it and change it to `minimumToolsVersion="Xcode 7.0"`